# Stopping FORM from submission and popping a dialog box

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea, xhtml, javabeans

In the image attached, each button is command submit button {Brewery1, Distributor1, .....etc} and submits form (HTTP POST method) and loads to next page upon clicking. What I am trying to do is to pop up a dialog box upon clicking a button to ask user to make sure to submit the form. I have checked various other sources but could not find any suitable solution as the form is submitted already when the button is clicked. Any help in the regard would be appreciated. [![`Submits Buttons

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html " xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>
<h:head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css_style.css"/>
    <title>The Beergame New</title>
    <link rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          href="#{resource['images:MunichBrewery.png']}"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="inputForm" class="input_form">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="public"/>
        <h2>Welcome to the Beer Game!<br/></h2>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css_style.css"/>
        <h:graphicImage styleClass="TUMBrewery" url="#{resource['images:TUMBreweryBlue.png']}"
                        height="110"
                        alt="TUM Brewery"/>

        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css_style.css"/>
        <h:graphicImage url="#{resource['images:MunichBrewery1.png']}"
                        alt="Munich Brewery"/>
        <br/>What is your role? <br/>

        <div id="button1-block">

        <br/> <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Brewery 1" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Brewery1')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit1" value="Distributor 1" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Distributor1')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit2" value="Retailer 1" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Retailer1')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton id="submit3" value="Wholesaler 1" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Wholesaler1')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <br></br><h:commandButton id="submit4" value="Brewery 2" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Brewery2')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit5" value="Distributor 2" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Distributor2')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit6" value="Retailer 2" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Retailer2')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit7" value="Wholesaler 2" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Wholesaler2')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <br></br><h:commandButton id="submit8" value="Brewery 3" styleClass="button1">
        <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Brewery3')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit9" value="Distributor 3" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Distributor3')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit10" value="Retailer 3" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Retailer3')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton id="submit11" value="Wholesaler 3" styleClass="button1">
            <f:actionListener binding="#{loginweb.setNewUsernameAndCreateUser('Wholesaler3')}"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        </div>

    </h:form>

    <h:form id="dialogform">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>
        <div id="dialog" class="block_screen" style="display: none">

            <div class="loading-screen" style="margin-top: 10%;">
                <div id="container">
                    <div class="pour"></div>
                    <div id="beaker">
                        <div class="beer-foam">
                            <div class="foam-1"></div>
                            <div class="foam-2"></div>
                            <div class="foam-3"></div>
                            <div class="foam-4"></div>
                            <div class="foam-5"></div>
                            <div class="foam-6"></div>
                            <div class="foam-7"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="liquid">

                            <div class="bubble bubble1"></div>
                            <div class="bubble bubble2"></div>
                            <div class="bubble bubble3"></div>
                            <div class="bubble bubble4"></div>
                            <div class="bubble bubble5"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                <h2 style="color:#0065bd;">Please wait until the administrator has added you to a game!</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

<!--            <div class="modal">-->
<!--                <div class="modal-dialog">-->
<!--                    <div class="modal-header">-->
<!--                        <h2>Please wait until the administrator has added you to a game!</h2>-->
<!--                    </div>-->
<!--                </div>-->
<!--            </div>-->

        </div>
    </h:form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.pour')
                .delay(2000)
                .animate({
                    height: '360px'
                }, 1500)
                .delay(1600)
                .slideUp(500);

            $('#liquid')
                .delay(3400)
                .animate({
                    height: '170px'
                }, 2500);

            $('.beer-foam')
                .delay(3400)
                .animate({
                    bottom: '200px'
                }, 2500);
        });

        if (('${loginweb.newUserName}' !== "" || '${loginweb.userName}' !== "") &amp;&amp; '${loginweb.newGameID}' === "") {
            document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("inputForm").style.opacity = '0.0';
        } else if ('${loginweb.newGameID}' !== "") {
            window.location.replace("beergame_user.xhtml");
        }
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXTEd.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXTEd.jpg)Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet has a syntax error: `js:168 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'`

Comment: Whats this `h:head` business?

Comment: @GetSet It's XHTML that's using namespace qualifiers.

Comment: @geocodezip I am not sure of reason, it is working fine in intelliJ. the image of the output of code is attached at end of question.

Comment: The line: `if (('${loginweb.newUserName}' !== "" || '${loginweb.userName}' !== "") &amp;&amp; '${loginweb.newGameID}' === "") {` is not valid javascript.